# JSONSerialization returning false in app and true in postman

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swifty-json, nsjsonserialization

I'm using Alamofire with SwiftyJSON to post HTTP requests. An option in the app allows the user to choose a product and a variable option related. I'm using `JSONSerialization` to encode the JSON response and post it back with the request.

When testing on Postman I get a positive result while in the app it returns false result. I'v been struggling for hours to find a solution and nothing yet.

The code to post the request:

```
   var optionDictionary = [String:AnyObject]()
    var requstParams = [String:String]();
    requstParams["product_id"] = self.productId
    requstParams["quantity"] = self.quantityValue.text
    do {
        let jsonSortData =  try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self.optionDictionary, options: [])
        let jsonSortString = String(data: jsonSortData, encoding: .utf8)!
        requstParams["option"] = jsonSortString
    }
    catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    NetworkManager.sharedInstance.callingHttpRequest(params:requstParams, apiname:"api/addtoCart", cuurentView: self, method: .post, encoding: JSONEncoding.default){success,responseObject in
        if success == 1{
            let dict = responseObject as! NSDictionary;
            NetworkManager.sharedInstance.dismissLoader()
                self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                if dict.object(forKey: "success") as! Int == 1{
                    let data = dict.object(forKey: "total") as! String
                    self.tabBarController!.tabBar.items?[3].badgeValue = data.components(separatedBy: " ")[0]
                    self.navigationCart(cartCount:data.components(separatedBy: " ")[0])
                    if self.goToBagFlag == true{
                        self.tabBarController!.selectedIndex = 3
                    }

                }
        }
    }
```

Xcode Debugger shows

> url https://www.example.com/api/addtoCart
>   params ["product_id": "23490", "quantity": "1", "option": "{\"2008\":\"7404\"}"]
>   Success returnData {"success":false,"error":{"option":{"2008":"Option is required!"}}}

While in Postman when I use the following values

```
{
"quantity": "1",
"product_id": "23490", 
"option": {"2008":7403}
}
```

I get a successful return = true.

I'm confused what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The other thing you should examine when making post requests is sending what the API wants. Does the API really want a strings for numeric items?

Comment: https://medium.com/@sdrzn/networking-and-persistence-with-json-in-swift-4-part-2-e4f35a606141

Comment: Oh! I see it now...the 7404 value in the debugger is a string. Then one you're doing successfully is an Int.

Answer (score 0):

OK, dude...here goes...

Your issue is with the 2nd line:

You're declaring your dictionary with a `String` as the value.

```
var requestParams = [String:String]()
```

The API wants an `Int` for the value.

```
"option": {"2008":7403}
```

I would recommend you stop using `SwiftyJSON`, as `Codable` is a "factory" protocol. You model a struct the way you want the data modeled. In this case, here's what your raw JSON would look like as a `Codable` struct.

```
struct Order: Codable {
    let quantity: String
    let productID: String
    let option: [String: Int]
}
```

Let's say you want to create an order...here's how you'd do it:

```
let order = Order(quantity: "1",
                  productId: "23490",
                  option: ["2008":7403])
```

When you utilize the encoder, you'll use it like this:

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.keyEncodingStrategy = .convertToSnakeCase
```

`convertToSnakeCase` will convert your JSON key from `productId` to `product_id` and your declarations will follow Swift's convention of camelCase.

Here's a [post you may find helpful](https://medium.com/@sdrzn/networking-and-persistence-with-json-in-swift-4-part-2-e4f35a606141)